# Blender can't display a "face sheet" object

Tags: units

I am a software engineer and I am new to Blender. I need to do some programming on 3d reconstruction and geometry on some 3D objects, but I want to display it on Blender for some sort of testings.

[image: The .obj file of a face]

I imported this .obj file into Blender but nothing is showing up on the plane.

My .obj file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wzOLKxNWpHEQ5WDSKY_2E8Rz2pR3lptA/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 0):

The mesh is far away from the origin. To fix that, keep your object selected, right click > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to reset its location and put it at the center of the scene.